# Store output of system command into local char array in c

Tags: c++, c

Is there any way to store output of system command into char array, since system command is returning only int.

Comment: The int isn´t the output, but the exit value. ... Look into piping.

Comment: Please edit your question with the platform that you are using.  The task you need to perform may be more efficient with platform specific functionality.

Comment: Which language?  In C++, the preferred data structure for text is `std::string` which is not available in C.  Remember in C, there is a lot of effort in dynamic text processing, because you need to have a dynamically allocated array of characters.  In C++, the `std::string` class handles this for you.  So, choose your tags wisely.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to retrieve the output of `system(3)`. Well, you could redirect the output of whatever command is executed to a file and then open and read that file, but a more sane approach is to use `popen(3)`.

`popen(3)` replaces `system(3)` and it allows you to read the output of a command (or, depending on the flags you pass it, you can write to the input of a command).

Here's an example that executes `ls(1)` and prints the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *ls_cmd = popen("ls -l", "r");
    if (ls_cmd == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "popen(3) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    static char buff[1024];
    size_t n;

    while ((n = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff)-1, ls_cmd)) > 0) {
        buff[n] = '\0';
        printf("%s", buff);
    }

    if (pclose(ls_cmd) < 0)
        perror("pclose(3) error");

    return 0;
}
```